# MySQL 8.0 "show columns from ..." query returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql

I am running MySQL 8.0.22 on Mac OS 11.7. Before I upgraded MySQL from 5.6, the following query worked fine.

`show columns from Viewing where field="type";`

But now, after upgrading to MySQL 8.0.22, I get the expected 1 row returned when I'm logged into MySQL as `root`:

```
mysql> show columns from Viewing where field="type";
+-------+------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type                                           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| type  | enum('edits','other','page','preview','whole') | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But when I log in as the user I've created for the webpage that issues this query, 0 rows are returned. This user is `view_pjn@localhost`, and its grants are:

```
mysql> show grants for "view_pjn"@"localhost";
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for view_pjn@localhost                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `view_pjn`@`localhost`                       |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `blog`.`viewing` TO `view_pjn`@`localhost` |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I log into MySQL 8.0.22 as `view_pjn`, I get the following when I issue this query:

```
mysql> show columns from Viewing where field="type";
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I have searched [MySQL 8.0 Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/) and it would seem that as `view_pjn@localhost` has `SELECT, INSERT` privileges on `blog.viewing`, it ought to be able to issue a `show columns from Blog.Viewing` query.

If anyone can tell me why `view_pjn` is getting 0 rows returned, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Can other users (e.g. root) do that `show columns`? I just tested it on MySQL 8.0.29. I created a user with the same grants that you show. It works fine for me.

Comment: Not sure why it would be related to the upgrade, but what happens if you use `show columns from blog.viewing where field="type";`?

Comment: @EdmCoff same thing--MySQL returns the empty set.

Comment: @BillKarwin root, as I say in my posting, returns the expected row.